# Azure Easy API JavaScript: How to return multiple result set from MSSQL query

Tags: javascript, sql-server, azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-app-api

I have created an Azure Easy API (on an app service that was recently migrated from a mobile service). I want to return three result sets from an SQL stored procedure. But it only returns the first result set. I have read that setting `multiple` attribute of `query` to `true` would allow returning multiple result sets, but I am not sure how to do it. That's what my azure API looks like:

```
exports.get = function(request, response) { 
    var mssql = request.service.mssql;
    var param1 = request.query.pollid;
    var param2 = request.query.userid;
    var sql = "EXEC poll.GetPollsData @pollid = ?, @userid = ?";

    mssql.query(sql, [param1, param2], {
        success: function(results) { 
                 response.send(200, results); 
            }, error: function(err) {
                response.send(400, { error: err });        
        }
    });
};
```

`GetPollsData` stored procedure returns three result sets (for polls, questions and options). But the API only shows first table on client side (in `pollData` below).

This is the client side JavaScript:

```
client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient(a, k);
client.invokeApi('getpollsdata', {
    method: 'get',
    parameters: {
        pollid: p,
        userid: u,
    }
}).done(function(results) {
    pollData = JSON.parse(results.response);
}, function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use the [`execute()`](https://azure.github.io/azure-mobile-apps-node/module-azure-mobile-apps_src_data_execute.html#~execute) function in Azure Mobile Apps in Node.js, and add the parameter `multiple` to true as described at http://azure.github.io/azure-mobile-apps-node/jsdoc_data.execute.js.html#line55.

E.G.

```
module.exports = {
    "get": function (req, res, next) {
        var query = {
            sql:'EXEC [dbo].[SampleProcedure]',
            multiple:true
        };
        req.azureMobile.data.execute(query).then(function(results){
            console.log('results',results);
            res.json(results);
        })
    }
}
```

It will return an array which contains multiple result arrays.

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Thanks Gary. But I don't think `req.azureMobile` works in mobile service even after migration to app service. Could you please verify?

Comment: I have tried in Easy APIs in Mobile Apps. Please check your Easy Apis after migrating Mobile services to Mobile Apps.